# generating a random DNA sequence and finding out the CpG islands

Tags: python, random, sequence, bioinformatics, shuffle

I am trying to generate a random DNA sequence with the given amount of **A**, **G**, **T**, and **C**'s; using the `random` function in Python.

How can I shuffle these individual strings in the list?

I want to iterate over the 10 sequences in this list, but I am stuck here:

```
import random

finalList = ['AGTCTTTGTGT', 'ACGCGTAAACG', 'AGGGTCTC',...]

for items in finalList:
    random.sample(items, k=len(items)) #how can I fix this?
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use sample() or [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function in the random module to randomly shuffle the A, G, T, and C's while keeping the same number of each letter (e.g. AGT > GAT). Note, you need to join the resulting characters to create a new string.

```python
import random

final_list = ['AGTCTTTGTGT', 'ACGCGTAAACG', 'AGGGTCTC']

for s in final_list :
    result = "".join(random.sample(s, k=len(s)))
    print(s, ">", result)
```

**Output:**

```
AGTCTTTGTGT > TGTCGGATTTT
ACGCGTAAACG > AGAGCCATCGA
AGGGTCTC > GCTGCGTA
```

Use list comprehension to create a new list of sequences:

```
result = ["".join(random.sample(s, k=len(s))) for s in final_list]
print("orig_list", seq_list)
print("new_list ", result)
```

**Output:**

```
orig_list ['AGTCTTTGTGT', 'ACGCGTAAACG', 'AGGGTCTC']
new_list  ['ATGTCGTTTTG', 'CCAGAACAGGT', 'GGATCTCG']
```

Comment: thanks! when I do this, why it's returning a result like this: ['G', 'C', 'T',..] instead of [GCT...]?

Comment: @YaseminDilaraSucu You must join the characters to create a new string from the result; try `result = "".join(random.sample(items, k=len(items)))`

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much! Only thing is once I did that it returns as joining all the 10 sequences together from that first list. What I wanted to do is shuffling every 10 strings in that list and return the shuffled 10 strings back.

Comment: @YaseminDilaraSucu updated answer. Added code to create a new list of the shuffled strings. Reply if that is what you're looking for or not.